# WordPress loop ignore first post of three separate meta_values

Tags: wordpress, loops, metadata, advanced-custom-fields

I have a loop that is pulling all of the news out, however there is three main stories set by ACF. These are Main, Secondary and Third. This wouldn't be a problem if there was only one post set to each field. However, the client wants to be able to just set a new Main post without having to worry about removing the old ones.

So to make that work I'm trying to get the loop to ignore the first of these three fields, while showing the rest AND the other posts that are set to 'No'.

I'm trying something like this but I just cannot see how else to do it.

```
$args = array(
                // 'offset' => 1,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,

                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'offset' => 1,
                        'key'       => 'main_story',
                        'value'     => 'Secondary',
                        'compare' => 'NOT',
                        )
                    ),

                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'offset' => 1,
                        'key'       => 'main_story',
                        'value'     => 'Third',
                        'compare' => 'NOT',
                        )
                    ),

                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'offset' => 1,
                        'key'       => 'main_story',
                        'value'     => 'Main',
                        'compare' => 'NOT',
                        )
                    ),
                );
```

I know offset removes the ability to paginate which is important, but I saw https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination and also was told a way to go around this. This part is more important for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I finally got around not being able to do the above

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>

<?php

$excluded_key = "main_story";
$excluded_val = array("Main", "Secondary", "Third");
$exclude_ids  = array();

?>

<?php

foreach ($excluded_val as $exclude) {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => 1,
        'order'                     => 'DESC',
        'meta_query'            => array(
            array(
                'key'               => $excluded_key,
                'value'             => $exclude,
                )
            )
        );

    $excluded_id = get_posts($args);

    foreach($excluded_id as $to_exclude) {
        $exclude_ids[] = $to_exclude->ID;
    }
}


?>

<?php

$args = array(
    'post__not_in'      => $exclude_ids,
    'paged'                     => $paged
    );

    ?>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
```